# Significant Reason behind Fraction(0.1) = 3602879701896397/36028797018963968

Tags: python, floating-point, fractions

I was looking at the [Python documentation of `fractions`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fractions.html) and trying this code:

```
from fractions import Fraction

>>> print("Fraction (0.5):", Fraction(0.5))
Fraction (0.5): 1/2
>>> print("Fraction (0.1):", Fraction(0.1)) 
Fraction (0.1): 3602879701896397/36028797018963968
>>> print(1/10) 
0.1
```

Looking at the `Fraction(0.1)` result I thought it was my computer problem, but when I tried it on several computers the results were same.

My question

1. is there any computational reason to choose these odd numbers `3602879701896397/36028797018963968` instead of `1/10` just like `1/2` as it chosen for `Fraction(0.5)`.
2. more of these exist in python?

Comment: The number `1/10` can't be represented exactly in binary, just as `1/7` can't be represented exactly in decimal.

Comment: For the canonical discussion on this issue, see http://floating-point-gui.de.

Comment: @Barmar oh i see, 1/7 not divisible exactly but 1/10 is mathematically exactly equals to 0.1

Comment: That's true in decimal. Things are different in binary. 1/2 and 1/4 are divisible exactly, but 1/10 is not.

Comment: 1/7 is just as "exactly divisible" as 1/10. In base 7, 1/7 is written "0.1". There is nothing special about base 10; it's just a common notational system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's because that's the integer ration for the float `0.1` (which can't be represented *exactly* with floats):

```
>>> (0.1).as_integer_ratio()
(3602879701896397, 36028797018963968)

>>> '{:.30f}'.format(0.1)   # just to show that it can't be represented exactly I print 30 digits of 0.1
'0.100000000000000005551115123126'
```

If you want correct `Fraction`s you need to use both arguments or pass in a string:

```
>>> Fraction(1, 10)
Fraction(1, 10)

>>> Fraction('0.1')
Fraction(1, 10)
```

Or [limit the denominator](https://docs.python.org/library/fractions.html#fractions.Fraction.limit_denominator) after creating it from a float (not guaranteed to work in all cases):

```
>>> Fraction(0.1).limit_denominator()
Fraction(1, 10)
```

---

As for your second question: There are infinitely many rational numbers (decimal numbers that *could* be represented exactly as Fraction) in math but a computer uses 64bits for `double`s (the Python `float` type). That means only a few real numbers **can** have an exact representation as `double`. So there are a lot of other numbers with the same problem, just to name a few:

```
>>> Fraction(0.2)
Fraction(3602879701896397, 18014398509481984)

>>> Fraction(0.3)
Fraction(5404319552844595, 18014398509481984)

>>> Fraction(1/3)
Fraction(6004799503160661, 18014398509481984)
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, any other exist or just for `0.1`

Comment: @nivas: this happens for any number that can't be perfectly represented in the binary representation. `0.1` is only one of many, many numbers for which this is the case. It's the drawback of floating point numbers.

Comment: There are infinitely many

Comment: @MSeifert `Fraction('0.1')` or `Fraction(0.1)` which is right & whats the difference?

Comment: `Fraction(0.1)` is (almost) always wrong because it first creates a float (which is inexact) and only then converts that inexact float to a `Fraction`. The `Fraction('0.1')` approach is (almost) always better because then the Fraction parses the string as exactly as possible, which is why it returns `Fraction(1, 10)`.

Comment: @MSeifert thanks for clarifying